# Can we remove SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat" from <!DOCTYPE dmodule SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">

Tags: xslt, dtd, doctype

Trying to transform one xml into another xml using xslt. However, I want to remove

SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat"
from my doctype declaration.

I've already tried

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE (node)&gt;</xsl:text>
```

but I am looking for a workaround using `xsl:output`

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
```

Expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE (node)>
```

Actual:

```
<!DOCTYPE (node)
 SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
```

Comment: Do you want to literally out `<!DOCTYPE (node)>`? That doesn't seem to be a valid DOCTYPE declaration. And which XSLT processor do you use? Why do you use `doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"` if you don't want/need it?

Comment: by node I meant my rootnode, e.g. <!DOCTYPE dmodule>. And if I remove doctype-system="about:legacy-compat", then the whole DOCTYPE declaration gets removed, whereas I only want to remove SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat" part from my DOCTYPE declaration

Comment: I think the behaviour is according to the spec, you might want to check wether your XSLT processor has an extension to allow more control of the doctype output, the commercial versions of Saxon 9 for instance have one, although I have not checked whether it helps for that particular case.